# how to interrupt a Scanf() in c, To exit from a scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I want to find a way to exit from a scanf() without interrupting the program running, I mean I want that program still running even if any data is typed. I am working on Linux

Here is the C Code :

```
char chaine1[256];
char chaine2[] = "exit";
int i;

do {                    
    //The loop allows to control if the data is coming 
    //and send it continuously trough ethernet.
    printf("preparing to send informations, exit to stop !\n");
    scanf("%s", &chaine1);
    i = strcmp(chaine1, chaine2); // Building the condition to exit
    printf ("i= %d\n",&i); 
   } while (i!=0);
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

PS : I am a beginner in c and I have no idea in multiplexing syscalls  and double threads so if you can guive me a concrets solution in your answer I would be thankfull

NO BODY SEEMS TO HAVE THE ANSWER !! 
I am desperate PLEAASE HELP ME !

Comment: `scanf("%s", &chaine1);` is wrong, a good compiler can tell you why.

Comment: So what is the solution ? :)

Comment: In a single thread there is no way of interrupting *any* call in the context of that thread.

Comment: _What_ should interrupt your `scanf` call? And _why_? You can't easily do exactly what you ask, and you haven't given enough context for us to suggest a better solution.

Comment: I want to interrupt the scanf for alloowing the program running without each time waiting the user typing a caracter and then enter!

Comment: Do you know about multiplexing syscalls like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)? If used carefully, it might be the solution of your whole issue....

Comment: As @JoachimPileborg said, you need 2 threads : one that will wait for user input while tho other is still running your instructions.

Comment: @Coconup: not necessarily, the OP might have some event loop (using `poll`...)

Comment: Notice that `scanf` returns the number of successively scanned items. On failure it returns some negative or zero number.

Comment: "without each time waiting the user typing a caracter and then enter" Sounds like all you want/need is unbuffered keyboard input.  Search SO for "unbuffered input [c]".

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches that could work:

1. use `scanf` in a separate thread from your main work. It will still block, but only that thread. If the user types "exit", your scanf thread will send some message to your worker thread telling it to shut down
2. use synchronous I/O multiplexing to interleave your main and user I/O operations in a single thread (this only really works if your main operations are indeed I/O dominated). The `select`/`poll`/etc. family of calls allow you to monitor both `STDIN_FILENO` and file descriptors associated with sockets simultaneously. You'll have to handle reading from `STDIN_FILENO` manually though, when it is readable, instead of using `scanf`/`fscanf` (and should use non-blocking reads).

The second option sounds more complex, but if you're doing I/O dominated work, you'll often have the framework in place already.

Note that neither of these involve interrupting `scanf` which, although possible, is a *terrible* option.

---

NB. I see that you're asking for concrete code - but both these approaches involve a significant amount of setup. You'll need to do some research and come back with a question that isn't just "please write all my code for me".

There still isn't enough context for me to know which of the two options is more appropriate for you anyway, and if you're reduced to describing your whole program and getting a stranger to re-write it for you, I don't know what to suggest. Maybe hire someone?

Comment: This is the good answer, and indeed it is quite complex if the OP is just beginning to learn C. To Omar Lazrak: Learn more about C programming first; later, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).